# The concept of Power series in Strang's Calculus Lectures : how to understand " matching at $x=0 \space f(0), f'(0), f''(0), f'''(0) ...$"?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, power-series, definition

Source : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4ceWhmXxcs

[image]

In his Calculus Course , Pr. Strang kindly takes the pain to explain to the layman the concept of Power series.

The basic idea, he says, is to match at a given value , say $x=0$, all the following outputs : $ f(0), f'(0), f''(0), f'''(0) ...$.

He takes as example the function defined by $e^x$, for which we have $f(0)= f'(0) = f''(0) = f'''(0) ... = 1$.

I understand that the goal is to find the coefficients $a_1 , a_2, a_3 ... a_n$ that will allow to represent a given function , say $f(x)=e^x$ by a function defined as a power series .

But I don't see what the " matching" means here ( matching what with what?) and how this idea of " matching" functions as an intermediary step towards the final goal.

Also ( and this is an addtional  question) I cannot see the relationship Strang seems to establish in his construction of the power series function ( i.e. in the determination of the coeffcients)  between the order of the derivative and the order of the term.

I cannot show any " work" here for I have to admit I am lost in darkness.

Comment: He's matching the various derivatives of $f$ at $0$ with the derivatives at $0$ of the polynomial he seeks. You can read about Taylor polynomials in any calculus book or various places on line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a function $f(x)$, the "plan" presented in Strang's lecture is to write it as
$$
f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots\tag{1}
$$
for some coefficients $a_0, a_1, a_2,\cdots$.

What "match" (at $x=0$) in Strang's words <sup>$\dagger$</sup> means is that you pick the coefficients in the way that all the derivatives of LHS and RHS (at $x=0$) *match*.

For example, one wants to

- match the value of $f$ (the LHS) with that of the series (the RHS) at $x=0$:
  $$f(0) = a_0+a_1\cdot 0+a_2\cdot 0^2+\cdots$$
- match the derivative of $f$ with that of the series  at $x=0$:
  $$f'(0) = a_1 +2a_2\cdot 0 +\cdots.$$
- match the second derivative of $f$ with that of the series  at $x=0$:
  $$f''(0) = 2a_2 + 6a_3\cdot0+\cdots.$$

This "matching" process tells you what the coefficients should be in terms of the derivatives of the function $f$ at $x=0$.

---

<sup>$\dagger$</sup> Check your mentioned [video starting at 1:40](https://youtu.be/N4ceWhmXxcs?t=100).